# Removing spaces and saving as list of objects

Tags: java, tokenize

I'm just wondering what procedure would be the most appropriate/most efficent way to remove spaces in a data file (.txt) and save the results as a list of objects?

Here is a snippet of the data:

```
2014-03-24 19:11:42.838  7611.668 UDP       192.168.0.15:5353  ->      224.0.0.251:5353        53     5353    12
2014-03-24 19:03:30.710  8061.709 UDP       192.168.0.12:137   ->    192.168.0.255:137        374    30432     9
2014-03-24 19:13:55.651  7246.821 UDP       192.168.0.21:1024  ->  255.255.255.255:1900        24     9640     8
```

Just looking to save them as a List of Flows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
String s = data.replaceAll("\\s", "");
```